# Github Actions OIDC error with ECR: "not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken" but permission is there?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, amazon-iam, openid-connect

I created a **Github Actions** oidc identity provider in aws.
I assigned it a role (`arn:aws:iam::NNN:role/GARole`) with the following trust policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::NNN:oidc-provider/token.actions.githubusercontent.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                },
                "StringLike": {
                    "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub": "repo:myuser/myrepo:*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I then created the following (customer-managed) **permissions policy** and attached it to the role:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "General",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:BatchDeleteImage"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:NNN:repository/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So now when you select the role in AWS IAM, under the permissions tab you see the permissions policy and under the *trust relationships* tab you see the trust policy.

In my Github Actions pipeline I use **aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1.6.2**:

```yaml
    - name: Check out code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2.2.0
      with:
        role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_ROLE_TO_ASSUME }}
        aws-region: us-east-1

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1.6.2
```

This is the result:

```
Run aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1.6.2
  with:
    skip-logout: false
    registry-type: private
  env:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-1
    AWS_REGION: us-east-1
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ***
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ***
    AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: ***
Error: User: arn:aws:sts::***:assumed-role/GARole/GitHubActions is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: * because no identity-based policy allows the ecr:GetAuthorizationToken action
```

**Q:** Why is it not finding the `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` permission? It's there in the attached permissions policy??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at examples related to the `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` permission specifically, I noticed that they all used **"*"** as the resource, so separating it out into its own statement got my pipeline working again!

```json
        {
            "Sid": "AuthOnly",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
```